# Wrapping a 2D image on a 3D sphere

Tags: python, image

I have a simple code that creates a sphere.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

and I would like to add an image of the Sun and 'wrapped' around the sphere made. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, Unwrap the uv sphere(it's already done but just in case), add the texture of the sun in the image editor(just drag it in), plug colour to an emission shader, mix it with the bsdf as well, increase value at what ever size you like, turn on bloom if you are on eevee.